# Finding the equation of the normal to parabole

Tags: derivatives, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the equation of the normal line to the parabola $y=x^2+4x+1$,
>   which is perpendicular to the line connecting the start of coordinate system 
>   with the top of the parabola.

Can someone help me to start? I don't know how to start.

Thanks

Comment: What is the start of the graph?

Comment: What is the top of the parabola?

Comment: @user the point with coordinates of [0,0]

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The vertex of parabola, which I'm assuming is point on parabola with the lowest value (where f'(x) is 0)

Comment: Start by breaking the problem into subtasks. For instance, you have a line that’s described as passing though the origin and the top of the parabola, so start by finding the top of the parabola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user approach:

At first you are true on $(-2,-3)$, the vertex of parabola, Now we have:
$$m_{tangent}=\frac{-3}{-2} = y_x' = (x^2+4x+1)' = 2x+4 \Longrightarrow x=-\frac{5}{4}$$
$$-\frac{2}{3}=-m_{tangent}^{-1}=m_{normal}=\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\frac{y+39/16}{x+5/4} \Longrightarrow 32x+48y=-157$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We can proceed as follows

- find the vertex of the parabola, that is $(x_0,y_0)$
- determine the slope $m$ for the line connecting the origin with the vertex
- find the tangent line to the parabola with slope $m$
- determine the perpendicular to this tangent at the given point

Comment: I found the vertex if the parabola $(-2.-3)$, but how do I find the slope?

Comment: @Daniel What is the line trough the vertex and the origin?